# Adding a link to the EPiServer help menu

Tags: episerver, episerver-6-r2

I'm working on an EPiServer 6 R2 site and the client would like to add a link to the Help menu that appears at the top right hand side of the interface. Currently it lists CMS, Composer, Online Center etc and each of these link off to an external web page.

Does anyone know how to add another link to this menu? The client has their own support site that they would like to link to.

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 3):

I just realised this is possible via the web.config/episerver.config too

Try adding something like this into the relevant section

```
  <episerver.shell>
    <navigation>
      <add text="Intranet" menuPath="/global/intra" url="http://intra" sortIndex="100" />
    </navigation>
  </episerver.shell>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a MenuItem or a MenuProvider

There's a great guide [here](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-6/EPiServer-CMS-60/OnlineCenter-Developer-Documentation/#ExtendingNavigation)

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response, but I'm not sure that's quite right. That adds the link to the main menu i.e. the options directly underneath the CMS menu, not in the help list on the right hand side. I think it must be along those lines, but not quite that option....any ideas?

Comment: You need to specify the menu path.

All menu items in the top menu are in the "/global" bucket. The next segment is the name of menu section, e.g. "/global/cms". The last segment represents the actual user interface, e.g. "/global/cms/edit"

I have checked in reflector and the path you would need to use is "/global/help"

Comment: just confirmed this as working using the following

[MenuItem("/global/help/internalsupport", Text = "Internal Support", Url = "www.somesupporturl.com")]

Comment: Hi Tom - thanks so much for your response. What type of control do I need to use - does it need to be an .aspx page, user control or class? It doesnt really need any presentation controls as it will merely print out a link. Thanks.

Comment: Hi higgsy, if it's just a link, try using the other answer above, adding the navigation section into the config file